# How to find all elements that contain a certain attribute in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following code

```
<button az-name="btn1">A sample button</button>
<p>A sample text</p>
<p az-name="p1">Another sample text</p>
```

Now I have to get reference to the button element and the 2nd paragraph element. How can I accomplish this in Javascript or jQuery?

Comment: use `$('[az-name]')` with jquery or `document.querySelectorAll('[az-name]')` with pure js

Comment: `var x = document.querySelector('[az-name="btn1"]')` or for all of a certian attribute `var xs = document.querySelectorAll('[az-name]')`

Answer (score 1):

**With Jquery** you can **use the attribute selector**, as follows:

Either, to **find the p/button with the particular attribute**:

```
$button = $("button[az-name]");
$parag = $("p[az-name]");
```

Or, to **find any tags with the particular attribute**:

```
$button = $("[az-name='p1']");
$parag = $("[az-name='btn1']");
```

Or mix the both solutions.

**Note that you can use also that :**

> Attribute Contains Selector [name*="value"]: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing the a given substring

like this :

```
$all_az = $("[az-*='btn1']");
```

To **get all tags which have an attribute begining with "az-"** for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$("[az-name]")
```

For tweaking- [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cjPb7GZFFzENYPFANXJk?p=preview)

For reference - [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)